# Displaying Data from Multidimensional Array in D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, multidimensional-array, d3.js

I'm trying to display data from a multidimensional array using d3. Using the code below, nothing is appearing in the browser. Inspecting element shows that the text of each element in each array exists, but they are just not appearing on the page. However, when I remove the lines that have been commented below, I get the example output below:

```markdown
1,3,3,5,6,7

3,5,8,3,2,6

9,0,6,3,6,3

etc ...
```

How can I modify the code so that I can display something like this:

```markdown
1 3 3 5 6 7

3 5 8 3 2 6

etc...
```

The code:

```js
var dataset = [
    [1,3,3,5,6,7],
    [3,5,8,3,2,6],
    [9,0,6,3,6,3],
    [3,4,4,5,6,8],
    [3,4,5,2,1,8]
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("p")                 
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p") // removing
    .selectAll("text") // these
    .data( function(d,i,j) { return d; } ) // lines
    .enter() // text displays normally
    .append("text")
    .text( function(d,i,j) { return d; } )
    .attr("x", function(d,i,j) { return (i * 20) + 40; })
    .attr("y", function(d,i,j) { return (i * 20) + 40; })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("fill", textColour);
```

This is what inspecting element gives with a different array of numbers:

[image]

Comment: You're mixing SVG elements `g` and `text` with non-SVG element `p`. That's not valid; the browser doesn't know how to render that. If your viz is going to be all text, then stick with just plain html elements. If you need to use SVG (because there'll be some graphics coming), then lose the `p`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but this is basically the canonical [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) example -- http://jsfiddle.net/f4vAm/1/

Comment: @meetamit the same happens if I replace all "p" with "text".

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'll add an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there, there are only two minor things:

- As pointed out by metaamit, there's no `p` element in SVG -- use `g` instead.
- For the y position, use index `j` of the parent element instead of `i`.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f4vAm/1/).

Comment: I initially had the lines:
                .selectAll("p") and .append("p") //removing with the "p" as "text", do you know why the text didn't display then?

Comment: You can't nest `text` in `text` elements either in SVG.

Comment: it doesn't work with me! I received an error : "Error: <text> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN"." in this line : return (j * 20) + 40; J is a text element not a scalar.